# Removing instances of a particular tag that contains a specific attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to remove all instances of `<br type="_moz />` from within a page. I'm completely stuck as to how about accomplishing this.

Comment: Is that a typo.  Should it be: `<br type="_moz" />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to match the tags that you want to [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$('br[type="_moz"]').remove();
```

Also fix your markup as it has a missing double quote for the `type` attribute:

```
<br type="_moz" />
```

Comment: Perfect! that worked. I need to research as to exactly why it did.